# ProcessingJS - Multiple datatypes in a single array

Tags: arrays, processing, processing.js

I'm using ProcessingJS and I'd like to use multiple datatypes in a single array. I'm trying to do it on [Khan Academy](http://khanacademy.org).

Any help? I'm sorry my question is so small, but I don't feel there is sufficient info to provide here.

Comment: can you give a simple example of an array you wish to make and how you are going to use it.

Comment: Floats and booleans.

EDIT: Could make the boolean a float but I don't wanna :P

EDIT 2: Why do you need an example? Why can't you just provide an answer? Why are people so nosy -_-

Answer (score 0):

You **could** just use an array of Objects. Then you'd use the **instanceof** keyword to check which type a particular index is, and you'd **cast** to that type to use it. Something like this:

```java
void setup(){
  Object[] array = new Object[3];
  array[0] = true;
  array[1] = 1.0;
  array[2] = "hello";

  if(array[0] instanceof Boolean){
    println((Boolean)array[0]);
  }
}
```

But this isn't a very great design. Chances are there's a better way to encapsulate your data: maybe in multiple arrays, or maybe in a class that contains your multiple datatypes. That's why people are asking for an example of what you want to do, because the real answer is probably not to put multiple types into one array.

Comment: "Cannot cast Object to float"

Comment: @LoganDark Use an upper-case F `Float`, not a lower-case f `float`.

Comment: sorry, didn't know JavaScript had dynamic variables

Comment: I did say processingJS, sorry :P